# Finding set of specific instances in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a table subscriptions.
This table has a column user_id (A subscription has_one user)
A user has a ranking (A user has_one ranking).
I have an array @subscriptions with several instances of Subscription.
I want to find and count all the instances of Subscription in @subscriptions where user.ranking = "value"

I tried writting something like

```
@subscriptions.where(user.ranking = "value").count
```

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have no access to `user` properties without making a join with the users table.
On lesser versions of Rails you could do it like this:

```
Subscription.joins(:user).where("users.ranking = 'value'").count
```

Comment: @DavidGeismar You could always vote up and accept the answer if it helped.